# Building a dictionary from a tab delimited file in a pythonic way

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

I've written the following function that takes a tab delimited file (as a string) and turns it into a dictionary with an integer as a key and a list of two floats and the value:

```
def parseResults(self, results):
    """
    Build a dictionary of the SKU (as key), current UK price and current Euro price
    """
    lines = results.split('\n')
    individual_results = []
    for i in range(1,len(lines)-1):
        individual_results.append(lines[i].split('\t'))
    results_dictionary = {}
    for i in range(len(individual_results)):
        results_dictionary[int(individual_results[i][0])] = [float(individual_results[i][1]), float(individual_results[i][2])]
    return results_dictionary
```

I've been reading about using list comprehension and also dictionary comprehension but I don't really know what the best way to build this is.

I think I can simplify the first list build using:

```
individual_results = [results.split('\t') for results in lines[1:]]
```

but I don't then know the best way to create the dictionary. I've got the feeling this might be possible in a neat way without even creating the intermediate list.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Could you mention what `results` looks like??

Comment: Hi,

`results` looks something along the lines of:

`sku\tdelivered-price-gbp\tdelivered-price-euro\tid\n32850238\t15.53\t35.38\t258505\n` e.t.c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
import csv
import StringIO
results = "sku\tdelivered-price-gbp\tdelivered-price-euro\tid\n32850238\t15.53\t35.38\t258505\n"

data = list(csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(results), delimiter='\t'))
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[{'sku': '32850238', 'delivered-price-euro': '35.38', 'delivered-price-gbp': '15.53', 'id': '258505'}]
```

Of course, if you can read from an actual file, you can skip the stringIO part.

To build the type of dictionary you want, you would do this:

```
data = {}
for entry in csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(results), delimiter='\t'):
    data[entry['sku']] = [entry['delivered-price-gbp'], entry['delivered-price-euro']]
```

Or even as a dictionary comprehension:

```
import csv
import StringIO
results = "sku\tdelivered-price-gbp\tdelivered-price-euro\tid\n32850238\t15.53\t35.38\t258505\n10395850\t35.21\t46.32\t3240582\n"

data = {entry['sku']: [entry['delivered-price-gbp'], entry['delivered-price-euro']] 
        for entry in csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(results), delimiter='\t')}
print(data)
```

But that's now getting highly difficult to read.

The output would in those two last cases be:

```
{'32850238': ['15.53', '35.38'], '10395850': ['35.21', '46.32']}
```

Comment: Can I ask, it terms of performance, how will this perform relative the the answer above (list comprehension, mappings one)?

Comment: Likely better. Much of the csv module is implemented in C. Definitely not worse, and in any case, performance is likely irrelevant. This is a simple task and will be done before you blink.

Comment: And for multiple lines of input, what would the output be?

A list of dictionaries with each entry corresponding to a different SKU? 

(For dataset `sku\tdelivered-price-gbp\tdelivered-price-euro\tid\n32850238\t15.53\t35.38\t258‌​505\n10395850\t35.21\t46.32\t3240582` 

results would be:

 `data[0] = above`, `data[1] = {'sku': '10395850', 'delivered-price-euro': '45.22', 'delivered-price-gbp': '35.21', 'id': '340582'}`

Comment: @Kali_89: Well, why not just try it? ;-) Yes, it would be a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `[x for x in something]` is simply `list(something)`.

Comment: @DSM: Good point. That's Zope damage from my side, there are classes it won't work with. :-) But in this case it works of course. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSV module from the standard library it has a method for reading straight to a dictionary
[csv.DictReader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
In [8]: from collections import defaultdict

In [9]: with open("filename") as f:
   ...:     dic=defaultdict(list)
   ...:     next(f)                #skip the first line 
   ...:     for line in f:
   ...:         k,v=line.split(None,1)
   ...:         dic[int(k)].extend( map(float,v.split()[:2]) )
   ...:         

In [10]: dic
Out[10]: defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {32850238: [15.53, 35.38]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can simply be:

```
def parseResults(self, results):  
    lines = results.split('\n')
    li_results = [x.split('\t') for x in lines]
    results_dict = {int(x[0]):map(float,[x[1],x[2]]) for x in li_results[1:]} # skip the header
    return results_dict
```

or if you want it shorter(not recommended):

```
def parseResults(self, results):
    return {int(x[0]):map(float,[x[1],x[2]]) for x in [i.split('\t') for i in results.split('\n')][1:]}
```

Output(from the string you have given):

```
{32850238: [15.53, 35.38]}
```

Comment: Like the look of this - only one thing I can see missing, with this am I not including the header rows?

To fix this would I just change the line `results_dictionary = {int(x[0]):map(float,[x[1]x[2]]) for x in individual_results}` to:

`results_dictionary = {int(x[0]):map(float,[x[1]x[2]]) for x in individual_results[1:]}`?

Comment: Why would you not recommend the second option?

Comment: @Schoolboy: I don't see why it would be faster. It does the same thing, just in one line. That's neither faster nor slower.